# Using `top` to output only the running processes, PIDs and users?

Tags: terminal, process, format, top

I'd like to run `top -n 1` so that it only outputs a list of running processes, their `PIDs` and the user that has run them (the "`COMMAND`", "`PID`" and "`USER`" columns).

I don't need any of the other columns of data or the 5 lines of system info that also gets printed at the top (usually they are useful, but not for what I plan to do with the output).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>f</kbd> while `top` is running (without `-n 1`), you can choose the columns displayed.

You will need to press <kbd>w</kbd> to maintain this selection on subsequent runs.

You will need to use `tail -n +StartLineNo` to skip the header lines, since there is a single pass in your output.

However, you will still find the file full of escape sequences, and you may find it easier to manipulate the output from `ps` with appropriate options to select the columns you want and then sorted by CPU use and possibly filtered with `head`.